# Change Chrome's user icon into a photo?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Chrome with multiple personalities, each with a different Google account. My primary Chrome user appears to have grabbed the icon from my Google+ profile.

The secondary user also has a Google Plus profile photo. Nevertheless, it won't let me pick that photo. Instead I get only some pre-built icons:

[image]

How do I get a photo on the second profile?